Docker compose up - my command is not failing despite non-zero exit status?
Within my team's CI/CD pipeline, we have the following Make recipe:
test-some-service:
    echo "Running some tests...." && \
    docker-compose up service-target-test && \
    status=$$?; \
    # ...
    exit $$status

Despite collecting the docker-compose exit status, when it fails, the CI pipeline still pass with a false positive.

service-target-test-1  | FAILED (errors=1)
service-target-test-1 | make: *** [Makefile:2: test] Error 1
exited with code 2
...
...
success!

This is causing developers to push breaking code without knowing the changeset is not passing our quality checks. We have tried to refactor this recipe multiple times but still getting the same issue. What are we doing wrong here?

Does $status have the value you want?  Can you split this into multiple commands so that Make exits on its own?  Does make exit with the correct status?

Hello @DavidMaze , this was just me knowledge sharing Q&A style. We've already fixed the problem. (One of our team members encountered this problem and I thought it would be nice to have this in SO) I appreciate your help though :)

Please use docker compose run instead of docker compose up:
test-some-service:
    set -e && \
    echo "Running some tests...." && \
    # ...
    docker-compose run --rm service-target-test



The run command acts like docker run -ti in that it opens an interactive terminal to the container and returns an exit status matching the exit status of the process in the container.

The docker compose run command is more suitable for running "one-off" or "adhoc" tasks.
See:

What's the difference between up, run, and start?
Should I use docker-compose up or run?

